# How do I add a regular expression in a path that is to be searched

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to grep a string in a folder that has many files. Below is the command from my script:

```
find /dir1/ERP-PFD -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il $FINALFINDCMD | grep "ERP-PFD"
```

Since the dir1(Name changed) has many files, the command is a bit slow. To overcome this, I wanted to grep only the files that falls under a given time interval. The `ERP-PFD` files in the `dir1` folder are differentiated by their dates. The names of the files are of the format `ERP-PFD.2018-05-12` `ERP-PFD.2018-05-13` and so on. Since I know the dates of the strings to be grepped, I wanted to minimize the find process by adding a regular expression in the `/dir1/ERP-PFD` path. Something like `/dir1/ERP-PFD.2018.05.*` so that it searches the strings only for the month of April. 
Please let me know how do I add the expression in the path. 
**Note**:- The `ERP-PFD` file will also be in a folder of that particular day. For example, if the ERP-PFD is of 2018-05-12, it will be in a folder `dir2.2018-05-12`. So the path with the regex must be something like this `/dir1/dir2.2018-05-*/ERP-PFD.2018-05-*`

Comment: Other than the `-regex` predicate?

Comment: Or just `-path` with a pattern rather than a regular expression. But I would run `grep` using `-exec` directly from `find` instead.